# Refreshing database information via PHP function with Javascript

Tags: php, javascript

I'm trying to get a span to refresh with a php function which queries the database for spaces. However, I can't figure out how to keep it refreshing the actual database content dynamically (preferably via a timer). Here's what I have so far

```
<script type="text/javascript">
window.onload = startInterval;
function startInterval()
{
        setInterval("startTime();",1000);
}

function startTime()
{
    document.getElementById('spaces').innerHTML = <?php echo get_spaces($id)?>;  
}
</script>
```

Comment: Setup a script that nicely formats your data (`json_spaces.php`) and just query it via AJAX every so often.

Comment: `<?php echo get_spaces($id)?>` will execute **server side** and echo a static value. The JavaScript is then compiled **client side** with that static value so it won't change on subsequent executions (in JavaScript).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're going to have to use Ajax to load content dynamically without reloading the page.

You will have to make a PHP script that will output only the content you want to load dynamically on the page and then load this script with Ajax.

There is an easy way to do this with jQuery, see this example: http://www.sitepoint.com/ajax-jquery/

Answer (score 1):

I assume get_spaces executes a query by a parameter id

Have this function return a result by

```
 echo json_encode($result);
```

Now, instead of function start_timer calling your php function statically as your example has above, have it return via ajax

```
 function start_timer(){
 $.ajax ({
 url: get_spaces.php?id=1, // replace the parameter with dynamic assignment
 dataType: json,
 Success: function(result){
 //iterate thru result json obj
 }
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

Like the other posters pointed out, you'll have to use AJAX to make this work.  Here is some pseudo code that might help you,

```
<script type="text/javascript">

window.onload = // Start your setInterval, pass it interval.ajax_call()

var interval = (function(

    // Store data here
    var data;

    return {

        // Make your ajax call within this function
        ajax_call: function(),
    }

)();
</script>
```

This way you can store the information from your database into data via the ajax callback.